# Is there any algorithmic approach for this problem?

Tags: c, algorithm, if-statement, embedded, simplicity-studio

I have set of opcodes to carryout a specific function but the tricky part is here: for example in the posted code below, channelABC is the input, which means:  if in my product side has channel A, or channel b, or channel c is selected, it should match,OR,  if in my product side . if  channel b and c are selected it should match, basically if one or more of the Channels match (with input side  or product side),- Led has to glow .

i tried to map it, but i am not sure of the right way to do it

```
typedef enum{
    ZoneA  = 0x01,
    ZoneB  = 0x02,
    ZoneC  = 0x04,
    ZoneD  = 0x08,
    zoneE  = 0x10,
    ZoneF  = 0x20,
    ZoneG  = 0x40,
    ZoneH  = 0x80,
    ZoneABCD = 0x0f,
    ZoneAB = 0x03,
    ZoneAC = 0x05,
    ZoneAD = 0x09,
    ZoneBC = 0x06,
    ZoneBD = 0x0A,
    ZoneCD = 0x0C,
    ZoneABC = 0x07 ,
    ZoneABD = 0x0B,
    ZoneBCD = 0x0E,
    NOZONE  = 0x00

}zone;


railzone =buffers[0];  //rail zone read the value , which is  the first element in the buffer when the packet info is transformed to buffer
            //railzone will have the input here
            if(railzone ==ZoneABCD || railzone == ZoneA  || railzone == ZoneB || railzone == ZoneC || railzone == ZoneD  || railzone == ZoneAB
                    || railzone == ZoneAC || railzone == ZoneAD || railzone == ZoneBC || railzone == ZoneBD || railzone == ZoneCD || railzone == ZoneABC ||
                    railzone == ZoneABD || railzone == ZoneBCD   )      
            {


            }
```

I am giving input as ZONEABC, AND I am having the zoneAB in my product and since two of the zoneA and b are present, it should glow the LED

Comment: I cannot see any input nor output. Please produce a [mre]

Comment: railzone is the input, which will have any member in enum has input, and output is i need led to glow

Comment: Isn't it something as simple as `if ((railzone & productside) != 0) { /* glow the LED here. */ }`?

Comment: Your question is completely incomprehensible. Can you please at least use proper punctuation and rephrase it in a clearer way?

Comment: Jack solution, works

Answer (score 1):

You can use concept of masks.
Define a Mask for which zones your product supports i.e. create a variable and set the bit for every zone your product supports.
For example, If your product supports Zone A and Zone C

(Considering your enum)

```
#define PRODUCT_MASK (ZoneA | ZoneC)
```

Then sanitize input as

```
if((railzone_input & PRODUCT_MASK)  != 0)
{
    // Zone is supported 
}
else
{
   // Zone is not supported
}
```

If your railzone_input is ZoneBC (i.e. 6) and as I considered in above example, your PRODUCT_MASK will be 5.  So 6 & 5 = 4 which is != 0  i.e. Zone is supported.

If your railzone_input is ZoneB (i.e. 2) then 2 & 5 = 0 which is == 0  i.e. Zone is not supported.

Answer (score 0):

It's not totally clear what you need to do but it looks like you want to carry out a specific operation if some bits of the variable are set, this can be done with `&` (and) operator.

For example, if you want to do something on any `railzone` which has zone A enabled (bit 0), then you could do

```
railzone = ZoneAB;

if ((railzone & ZoneA) == ZoneA) {
  // turn on led for ZoneA?
}
```

Comment: it is acting the way I want, can you tell me how you came up with this